# jQuery Hover Function - When hover over a DIV, an IMG (sprite) should change background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having a little issue over here.

I am trying to make a background image change to it's hover position (sprite), when i hover on a "DIV".

The image is inside this "DIV".

I have done an example in JSFIDDLE, but without sprite, just a background color.

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Sb2/)

Tried this, but nothing:

```
$( "#box" ).hover(function(){
    $( "#box_sm" ).css("background","black");
});
```

Comment: The inner div already has it's background set to white so doing it again isn't going to change anything. Also, for simple things like this it's easiest to just use CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/dXTjw/1/

Comment: First : in your fiddle you are not loading jQuery so it can't work. Second you are changing the background-color from white to white so it is normal you can't see the change, this is probably a more apropriate fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/c4Sb2/3/

Comment: Ups, my bad. Set to black.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSFiddle demo has 2 problems:

Firstly, jQuery isn't included (you can include it that with the Frameworks and Extensions dropdown in the left sidebar). Your demo is throwing:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Secondly, you're changing the `#box_sm` background colour from `white` to `white`, so you will not notice any changes even after jQuery is added.

Here is a [**modified JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Sb2/2/) that I've included jQuery on and set the default background colour of the `#box_sm` element to `blue`. When you now hover over the `#box` element, the `#box_sm` element's background will change to white.

---

If you want the background to change back when no longer hovering, you can drop the JavaScript completely and just make use of CSS's `:hover`:

```css
#box:hover #box_sm {
    background-color: white;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Sb2/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need js for it, you can do this in css only:

```
#box:hover > #box_sm{
   background: white;
}
```

---

As you want to change your sprite then you can try changing its `background-position` property like this:

```
#box_sm{
   background: url('yoururlofsprite') 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
#box:hover > #box_sm{
   background: url('yoururlofsprite') 20px 20px no-repeat;
}
```

---

If you are asking about why your fiddle is not working because you forgot to include jquery from the left top **Framewoks and Extensions**. Also change your background to other default color to see the code working.

#### [Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Sb2/8/)

Comment: In OP's code, the background is set but never changed back when the hover ends. With CSS the background changes back when no longer hovering.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, will check out